# How to calculate limits in triple integral?

Tags: integration

I have the next exercise of triple integrals:

$f(x,y,z) = \cos(x + y + z)$, Limited by planes $x=\pi, y=\pi, z=\pi
$

I have to find/determine the value for this.

**Specific Questions:** How can I start this exercise? how to stablish limits for each integral? or what is the correct way to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the domain of integration. What do you mean by "limited" ?
Because if you consider the three planes in 3D space they don't really define any domain. Their intersection is only one point and they don't create an enclosed volume.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, my teacher gave me the excersise as it's posted, I've been trying to solve it but can't find a way to stablish the limits for each integral, should I set the lower limits for each integral to 0 maybe and the higher limits to pi?

Comment: That would be a "valid" interpretation in my opinion. Another interpretation could be to start at $- \infty$ to $\pi$ or from $\pi$ to $+ \infty$ but it seems a bit odd to me and in any case it's not defined.

Comment: I would guess that a restriction to the first octant got lost, either in the problem writer's mind or its route from there to here.  In that case all three integrals should be from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: If the domain of integration is $[0,\pi]^3$, then an hint is that $\cos(x+y+z)$ is the real part of $\exp(ix)\exp(iy)\exp(iz)$.